# How to delete a shortcut made by a browser from apps in ubuntu 22?

Tags: shortcuts

I have created a shortcut for a website using brave browser, it shows inside the apps as shown in the bellow screenshot, I have no options to remove this shortcut, how to get rid of this shortcut?

[image]

[image]

See, we don't have much options:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, for brave-browser created shortcuts,
just open the shortcut, and on top you'll see the burger menu, click it and then choose uninstall as shown in the below image, (click the image to enlarge):

[image]

[image]